# SQL query with multiple LIKE operators, and BETWEEN dates statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running below query where I need to filter emails based on the subject line. There are 2 possible subject lines which get filter out fine if I omit the `BETWEEN start AND end` operator, but once I add that date filter, it gets ignored and returns results from all possible date ranges.

Long story short: how do I accurately combine 2 `LIKE` operators and 1 `BETWEEN` in one query?

Thank you

```
SELECT 
    `recipient` AS `to`,
    `subject` AS `subject`,
    `created_at` AS `sent_date`
FROM `sent_emails`
WHERE
    `subject` LIKE '% - Daily Logbook Summary'
    OR `subject` LIKE '% - Daily Guest Farewell Report'
    AND `created_at` BETWEEN '2021-03-13 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-14 00:00:00'
ORDER BY `subject`, `sent_date`;
```

Comment: If it is your database it would be better to add dedicated column to store a type of sent mail instead of text search in subject field. If  *Daily Logbook Summary* will change in future i.e. because of managers decision or additional languages you'll need to recode it everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AND binds stronger than OR so you need parenthesis:

```
SELECT 
    `recipient` AS `to`,
    `subject` AS `subject`,
    `created_at` AS `sent_date`
FROM `sent_emails`
WHERE
    (
      `subject` LIKE '% - Daily Logbook Summary'
      OR `subject` LIKE '% - Daily Guest Farewell Report'
    )
    AND `created_at` BETWEEN '2021-03-13 00:00:00' AND '2021-03-14 00:00:00'
ORDER BY `subject`, `sent_date`;
```

See also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html as an alternative way to express those two like expressions as one:

```
`subject` RLIKE '.* - Daily (Logbook Summary|Guest Farewell Report)$'
```

Comment: learned something new today, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your date arithmetic is presumably off because it includes `created_at` that are exactly at midnight on 2021-03-14.  I recommend that you *never* use `BETWEEN` on date/time values because the code often slightly differs from your intentions.

You can also simplify the subject logic using `substring_index()`:

```
WHERE substring_index(subject, ' - ', -1) in ('Daily Logbook Summary', 'Daily Guest Farewell Report') AND
      created_at >= '2021-03-13' AND
      created_at < '2021-03-14'
```

I think the substring index captures the logic you *really* want, which is that some set of strings occurs after the `-` in `subject`.